# Many to many Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Ok so I tried whith your answers, I can return Invoices associated to a user but i cant get the products inside this invoice, I want to get the Invoice associated to the user with his products only.

If i mention the id of the user who creates a product and the id of the invoice, i want the query to return me the invoice with the products associated to the id of the user mentionned.

when Iam using this :

```
        $Invoices = Commande::find(1)->whereHas('Product', function($query){
        return $query->where('products.user_id', 3);
    })->with('Product')->get();
```

I get only the Invoices.

But i want the Invoice and the products in this invoice that are associated to a certain user.

Comment: In the future, please do not post your code as images. **Code is text**, pleas copy, paste and format this properly into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's where the `whereHas()` method comes into place. You should be able to do something like this:

```php
$user = User::find($userId); // Let's assume `$userId` is `1`
$invoices = Invoice::whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($user) {
  return $query->where('products.user_id', $user->id);
})->get();
```

That will return all `Invoice` records that are associated with the `$user` record returned by `User::find($userId)` (again, in this case, `user_id: 1`)

You can see the full documentation here:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

---

Note: You might need to adjust the model/relationship names I used in the code above to fit your needs, but the basic idea remains the same.

Comment: This is working perfectly but can i Have the Invoice with the products ? (or only the products its fine)

Comment: `$invoices` is a list of the `Invoice` records. You can use `->with('products')` on your query anywhere before `->get()` to include each Invoice's products.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to get invoices and their products belonging to a specific user

```
// my user id is currently authenticated, user

Invoice::query()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->with('products')->paginate();
```